# Is it possible to access scope data in a returned success promise using resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs-scope, angular-promise, angular-resource

I have look up all related questions on stackoverflow but did not find any relevant answer. Maybe it's the elephant in the room that only I can't see but after wasting an entire day on this, I would really appreciate if someone can offer some insight.
I have a controller with a scope variable $scope.fruits that is using resource to post data to /fruits (contrived example)

```js
.controller('FruitsController', ['$scope', 'addFruitsFactory', 'sliceFruitsFactory', function($scope, addFruitsFactory, sliceFruitsFactory) {

        $scope.fruits = {
          seasonal: "",
          imported: "",
          exported: ""
        }

        btn_serveFruits = function() {

          // user selects a list of fruits from a select control in html. 
          // $scope.fruits is successfully bound to this select 
          // $scope.fruits has a list of selected fruits 
          addFruitsFactory.save($scope.fruits).$promise.then(
            function(response) {

              console.log('fruits in scope ' + $scope.fruis);
              // $scope.fruits is empty here. Is it possible to access 
              // $scope data here so it can be passed to the next factory?
              sliceFruitsFactory.slice($scope.fruits);


            },
            function(response) {
              $scope.message = "Error : " + response.status + " " + response.statusText;
            }
          );
        }


      }
```

Is it possible to access $scope.fruits in the success promise returned by the resource? 
Your response is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: No reason you can't access it there and it shouldn't be empty unless you have modified that object in code we can't see. Create a demo that reproduces problem.

Comment: Really bad practice creating variables that are global like ... `btn_serveFruits = function()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! Right!!I do not change it in anyway, I will recheck knowing it should not be empty. Thanks again.

Comment: btn_serverFruits is actually $scope.btn_serverFruits = function ()  and is linked to the html button with ng-click= btn_serverFruits . Is it still bad practice?

Comment: no not at all .... that's how angular works. What is shown though is the same as `window.btn_serverFruits = function...` which is very different

Comment: update: solved: Thanks a lot charlietfl, because you pointed me in the right direction , I was able to resolve the issue. I was resetting the $scope outside the promise which ended up resetting it. Typical newbie to 'asynchronous programming and angularJS' mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: hey...at least you now understand what was wrong and it sounds like you understand why

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Im not understanding you correctly.  Once you use the resource, the promise should return the object which you can use to populate scope.

```
service.save($scope.fruits).$promise.then(function(data) {
     $scope.fruits = data;

    //$scope.fruits now has the data to send to another factory/service 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! In this case, the promise  does not have any data, all the data is already in the scope object. so addFruitsFActory.save tells the server to do some book keeping and once that is done, sliceFruitsFactory proceeds with the next step of the use case. I only want to reuse the data that is already in the scope....but sliceFruits should only happen if fruits were added successfullly, hence the use of the promise.

Answer (score 0):

Write the method 'btn_serveFruits' as a scope method as below:

```
app.controller('FruitsController', ['$scope', 'addFruitsFactory', 'sliceFruitsFactory', function($scope, addFruitsFactory, sliceFruitsFactory) {

        $scope.fruits = {
          seasonal: "",
          imported: "",
          exported: ""
        }

        $scope.btn_serveFruits = function() {

          // user selects a list of fruits from a select control in html. 
          // $scope.fruits is successfully bound to this select 
          // $scope.fruits has a list of selected fruits 
          addFruitsFactory.save($scope.fruits).$promise.then(
            function(response) {

              console.log('fruits in scope ' + $scope.fruis);
              // $scope.fruits is empty here. Is it possible to access 
              // $scope data here so it can be passed to the next factory?
              sliceFruitsFactory.slice($scope.fruits);


            },
            function(response) {
              $scope.message = "Error : " + response.status + " " + response.statusText;
            }
          );
        }
      }
```